# How to filter products using category_id and brand in magento soap API v2

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

I have created a function to filter products by brands as follows:

```
$complexFilter = array(
    'complex_filter' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'manufacturer',
            'value' => array('key' => 'like', 'value' => $brand_id)
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'name',
            'value' => array('key' => 'like', 'value' => '%'.$name_keyword.'%')
        )
    )
);

$result = $soapClient->catalogProductList($sessionId, $complexFilter);
var_dump ($result);
```

This function return correct data.
but when I used category_ids in complexFilter it return me exception.

My Custom function for filter by brands and category_ids is as follows:

```
$complexFilter = array(
    'complex_filter' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'category_ids',
            'value' => array('key' => 'in', 'value' => array("353"))
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'manufacturer',
            'value' => array('key' => 'like', 'value' => $brand_id)
        )
    )
);

$result = $soapClient->catalogProductList($sessionId, $complexFilter);
var_dump ($result);
```

And Exception are :

```
{"faultstring":"Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object","faultcode":"SOAP-ENV:Server"}
```

How to filter products using category_id and brand in Magento SOAP API?

Comment: facing the same issue here. I basically want to look for a product with a certain value for my custom attribute GTIN. Got exactly the same exception.

Comment: Hello @Nico, you can refer my answer, I hope it is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finallly I have found my solution :

```
$allProductValue = (array)$soapClient->catalogCategoryAssignedProducts($sessionId, $category_id);
$result = array();
if(!empty($allProductValue))
{
    for($i = 0;$i < count($allProductValue);$i++)
    {
        $product_id = $allProductValue[$i]->product_id;
        /* get product info from product id */
        $attributes = new stdclass();
        $attributes->attributes = array('name', 'short_description', 'price');
        $attributes->additional_attributes = array('manufacturer');

        $productInfo = $soapClient->catalogProductInfo($sessionId, $product_id,'1',$attributes);
        $product_info = get_object_vars($productInfo);
        $manufacturer = get_object_vars($product_info['additional_attributes'][0]);
        if($manufacturer['value'] == $brand_id)
        {
            array_push($result,$product_info);
        }
    }
    if(!empty($result))
    {
        $returnResult = array('ProductList' => $result);
    }
    else
    {
        $returnResult = array('Message' => 'No Products founds of this brand');
    }
}
else
{
    $returnResult = array('Message' => 'No Products founds of this Category');
}
```

Comment: You can also accept your own answer ;)